# Are Vuetify SASS variables meant to work like this?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, saas

I want to customize the styles of the original [v-switch](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/switches/) component. I wanted to know if I can use Vuetify SASS variables in a specific way. The current directory structure is:

```
styles/
   components/
       _variables.scss
       _VSwitch.scss
   _index.scss
```

`_variables.scss` has:

```
$switch-thumb-width: 28px;
$switch-thumb-height: 28px;
$switch-thumb-top: calc(50% - 14px);
```

`_VSwitch.scss` has:

```
@import './variables';

.v-input--switch {
    width: $switch-width;

    &__thumb {
        width: $switch-thumb-width;
        height: $switch-thumb-height;
    }
}
```

Then, _index.scss has:

```
@import './VSwitch/VSwitch';
```

And then, I import this last file in my Vue app `main.js`.

As the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/) state, "The vuetify-loader will automatically bootstrap your variables into Vue CLI’s compilation process, overwriting the framework defaults."

**Method 1**

When I read the part about overriding SASS variables, I though I could simply do `$switch-thumb-width: 28px;` and the width of the switch would change automatically to 28px. I mean, I would need here only *_variables.scss*. Just set the new value of the variable and ready to go. But it is not the case.

**Method 2**

Instead, I have to manually especify the selector inside *_VSwitch.scss* and use the variables as **values**, like in `width: $switch-thumb-width;`. I would need here both *_variables.scss* and *_VSwitch.scss* files.

My question is: is **method 1** possible to do or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: Dont modify core files of vuetify. create custom scss file and import in main.js file. get id or class of element from inspect element of browser. and set your styles for it (with !important)

Comment: I prefer not to abuse of `!important`.

Comment: If you import correctly and according to priority, you will not need it either. I said it just for that reason

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. :) However, I'm not sure if I explained my self well, so I reformulated my question.

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC Hello, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec! I have no longer access to the project I was working on and it's been a long time so I can't really remember if I could solve it. I'm really sorry for not been able to help you.

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC Thanks for your answer! :-) Actually I solved it; I had to recompile (`npm run build` and not only `npm run serve`) to see the changes after having declared the variables as explained in the [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#vue-cli-install).